# pdflatex and enumlist counter problems

Tags: hyperref, lists, enumitem

I am trying to use the line that is commented out, but it fails unless I don't use hyperref.

The error message is rather cryptic as

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
```

I cannot seam to determine the cause of this.

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{enumitem, calc}

  \newlist{probenum}{enumerate}{1}
  \setlist[probenum]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}.}

\def\horizenum#1#2#3{
  \flushleft
  \dimen0 \linewidth
  \divide\dimen0 by #1\relax
  \def\item{\hfil\egroup\penalty50 \hfill
  \refstepcounter{#2}%
  \leavevmode\hbox to \dimen0 \bgroup\space#3\space}%
  \leavevmode\bgroup\hskip 0pt plus -1fill }

\def\endhorizenum{\hfil\egroup\endflushleft}

\begin{document}
  \newcounter{test}
  \setcounter{test}{0}
  %\begin{horizenum}{2}{probenumi}{\textbf{\arabic{probenumi}.}}
  \begin{horizenum}{2}{test}{\textbf{\arabic{test}.}}
    \item Monday
    \item Tuesday
    \item Wednesday
    \item Thursday
  \end{horizenum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For one, [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) redefines `\item` and only references an older version of `\item` as `\H@item`. However, perhaps you can mention what you're after exactly, since there may be a different way of achieving what you're after.

Comment: I tried to create an environment that I could use like an enumerate. I have a series of items (one in a column) and then a series in 2 columns continuing the same numbering (using the probenumi counter). Normally, I would use the multicols package, but the numbering has to be from left-to-right (effect of all odds in the first column and the evens in the second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load `hyperref` after you have provided your new definitions.  Generally `hyperref` should be loaded as late as possible, as it tries to modify and hook in to various preexisting commands.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}

\newlist{probenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[probenum]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}.}

\def\horizenum#1#2#3{
  \flushleft
  \dimen0 \linewidth
  \divide\dimen0 by #1\relax
  \def\item{\hfil\egroup\penalty50 \hfill
  \refstepcounter{#2}%
  \leavevmode\hbox to \dimen0 \bgroup\space#3\space}%
  \leavevmode\bgroup\hskip 0pt plus -1fill }

\def\endhorizenum{\hfil\egroup\endflushleft}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{horizenum}{2}{probenumi}{\textbf{\arabic{probenumi}.}}
\item Monday
\item Tuesday
\item Wednesday
\item Thursday
\end{horizenum}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the order of loading packages.

hyperref should be the last package and the environment must be loaded before hyperref

```
acts.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\newlist{probenum}{enumerate}{1}
  \setlist[probenum]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}.}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\horizenum#1#2#3{%
  \flushleft
  \dimen0\linewidth%
  \divide\dimen0 by #1\relax%
  \def\item{\hfil\egroup\penalty50 \hfill%
  \refstepcounter{#2}%
  \leavevmode\hbox to \dimen0 \bgroup\space#3\space}%
  \leavevmode\bgroup\hskip 0pt plus -1fill}

\def\endhorizenum{\hfil\egroup\endflushleft}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
  \newcounter{test}
  \setcounter{test}{0}
  \begin{horizenum}{2}{probenumi}{\textbf{\arabic{probenumi}.}}
%  \begin{horizenum}{2}{test}{\textbf{\arabic{test}.}}
    \item Monday
    \item Tuesday
    \item Wednesday
    \item Thursday
  \end{horizenum}
\end{document}
```